# Performance Evaluation for multiple classifiers in machine learning with Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I use four feature descriptors for five independent runs with each run randomly selecting the training set and testing set from the total labeled samples. SVM is the classifier. After acquiring the classification accuracy of each run for each descriptor, I get a accuracy matrix whose size is $5 \times 4$. Then I use the `ranksum` function in `MATLAB` to do Wilcoxon run sum test from pair-wise. Then I get the `p-value` matrix shown as follows:

[image]

I select $\alpha = 0.05$. If the `p-value` is less than $0.05$, then the difference is significant, and if the `p-value` is larger than $0.05$, then the difference between the two features is not significant. Is it right? Is the total procedure of statistical tests right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about significance and P.values. I am not sure Wilcoxon's Rank Sum test is the best way to compare accuracies, however, and hopefully someone will shed more light on this. 
I'd be considering Fisher's exact test for each pairwise comparison (Correct vs Incorrect calls).

Comment: Thank you, sir. This paper http://web.mit.edu/rudin/www/BDNVWorking14.pdf is using the Wilcoxon's Rank Sum test for pair-wise performance evaluation. And I have read some papers on Wilcoxon's Ranks Sum test and Wilcoxon's Signed Rank test. It seems both are valid for paired tests, and the Wilcoxon's Rank Sum test seems to be the paired t-test but with arbitrary data distribution instead of normal distribution. Thanks again!